# Error obteniendo epoch en objeto Date

Tags: java, android

Es algo básico pero estoy atascado en esta conversión de fechas:
recibo una fecha en `String` con formato

> 19/10/2017

y los tengo que convertir en epoch
para ello hago:

```
 Date dataObjUntil = null;
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
                        try {
                            dataObjUntil = sdf.parse(untilDate);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            Log.i("error", e.getMessage());
                        }
   long segundos = dataObjUntil.getTime()/1000
```

pero consigo

> 1484781000

que es

> jueves, 19 de enero de 2017 0:10:00

¿Alguien me puede decir en que me estoy equivocando? , no me interesa usar librerias tipo `JodaTime` ya que solo tengo que hacer esta operación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el formato de fecha mal. Utiliza `MM` para los meses en vez de `mm`  que representa los minutos:

```
Date dataObjUntil = null;
Date dataObjUntil = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try {
    dataObjUntil = sdf.parse(untilDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.i("error", e.getMessage());
}
long segundos = dataObjUntil.getTime()/1000
```

`mm` en minuscula representa los minutos, mientras que `MM` en mayuscula representa los meses de una fecha:

```
MM = meses
mm = minutos
```

Comment: genial !! muchas gracias